# Qu'est-ce que signifie «du plomb dans la tête»?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Bonjour, cette est ma première question écrité en français alors excusez-moi pour mon pouvre français, mon question est: Qu'est-ce que signifie «du plomb dans la tête»?, je ne peux le prendre littéralement dans ce contexte, merci.

Comment: Petite correction de ta question pour t'aider :

Bonjour, c'est ma première question écrite en français, alors excusez-moi pour mon pauvre français. Ma question est: qu'est-ce que signifie «du plomb dans la tête»?, je ne peux pas le prendre littéralement dans ce contexte, merci.

Comment: Not to be confused with "*avoir du plomb dans **l'aile***" which is always used in a negative sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Avoir du plomb dans la tête" or more oftenly "Avoir du plomb dans la cervelle " means to be intelligent, smart, crafty (not an empty head, it's filled with something and it's heavy)

It can also be used litterally to means "killed by a bullet in the head"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was confused with how to interpret it, I thought it could also mean that the person is hardheaded or dumb but it didn't make sense in context.

Comment: *Du plomb dans la tête* est un peu plus courant que *du plomb dans la cervelle*.